# File INPUT returning mangled file body in windows browsers but not mac

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, base64

I am reading the files within a file INPUT. When I run my code, in the file.body, I get the correct content which is just a text/csv in any browser on Mac OS X. But, on any browser in Windows 7, the file.body comes through base64 encoded. And, if I create a .txt file with the same content copied from the .csv, the file body is not base64 encoded.

How can I get the browsers on windows to return a non-base64-encoded file.body?

Comment: Just try explicitly mentioning the encoding when you are reading the file.

Comment: Hi Mr. Issac. Are you talking about <input type="file" accept=".csv">?

Comment: I am saying about to use something like as shown in url below: https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-character-encoding. This should give you some hints to proceed further or atleast to detect the encoding type and decode it accordingly if required.

Comment: Hi Mr. Issac. I think I was not clear. I need to read the file in the browser. Are you suggesting a service to determine file encodings?

Comment: Yeaah you are right.

Comment: I was able to decode the file when necessary but only within a try catch after I found out the file body was being base64 encoded. I did not find the answer to my question, "How can I get the browsers on windows to return a non-base64-encoded file.body?"

Comment: Are you setting Content-Type somewhere ?